# Strange behaviour when trying to restrict a view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, overlapping

I am trying to add a dynamic Bounding box to my camera layout,I have the following xml code in which I am trying to keep the bounding box from reaching the ShutterButton,I find that the box goes underneath the ShutterButton,I think it is because overlapping of views is allowed in RelativeLayout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_above="@+id/btn_capture"
             />
<com.example.mycameraapp.RectangleView android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@id/btn_capture"
     android:id="@+id/bound_box"
    />
<com.example.mycameraapp.ShutterButton android:id="@id/btn_capture"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
```

I would like it to not work in the region where ShutterButton specifically is,such that the ShutterButton remains the top Z element followed by the RectangleView on top of the CameraPreview which is simply a SurfaceView

Answer (score 1):

Your `btn_capture` was not created before you referenced it. Whenever you assign ids use `@+id` and whenever you refer ids use `@id` for avoiding errors

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.mycameraapp.ShutterButton android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/container"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_above="@id/btn_capture"
                 />
    <com.example.mycameraapp.RectangleView android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@id/btn_capture"
         android:id="@+id/bound_box"
        />
```

Comment: I would like ShutterButton and RectangleView to be the top-level z element which do not encroach on each other

Comment: Using your layout clicking the ShutterButton resizes the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Adding the RectangleView in my Java code as a child of the `FrameLayout` helped.Now,it draws itself behind the `ShutterButton` and allows me to click the Button even if it is drawn behind the `ShutterButton`.

```
 mPreview=new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);
    mBox=new RectangleView(this);
    container.addView(mPreview);
    container.addView(mBox);
```

In onPause,`container.removeAllViews();` ensures that the RectangleView is removed as well